# protobuf-net : simple inheritance : serialize as type , deserialize as sub-type throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization, deserialization, protobuf-net

`protobuf-net.2.1.0`

My understanding is that `protobuf-net` determines the message contract for de-serialization based entirely on info available on the receiver side -- the serialized packet itself is not relied upon to construct the message contract.  Specifically, class member attributes indicate the data-types and ordering of fields expected to be found in the packet.

Therefore since the sender-side is independent of the receiver-side, it should be possible to interpret any serialized packet as of a certain type if field data & order match that defined by the receiver-side proto contract.

Specifically with regards to inheritance, it should be possible to serialize an object of base-type and de-serialize as object of sub-type -- provided that the inheritance is properly notated.

However, for a simple inheritance hierarchy `DerivedClass : BaseClass`, I find that if I serialize as `BaseClass` and de-serialize as `DerivedClass` , the object returned will be of type `BaseClass`.

Here are the classes:

```
[ProtoBuf.ProtoInclude(1000, typeof(DerivedClass))]
[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
public class BaseClass
{
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = false, Name = @"Name", DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(2, IsRequired = false, Name = @"Index", DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.TwosComplement)]
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

Executing the following test method:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var baseObject = new BaseClass { Name = "BaseObject" };
        var derivedObject = new DerivedClass { Name = "DerivedObject", Index = 1 };

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, baseObject);
            Debug.WriteLine(stream.Length);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // either of next two lines will throw the invalid cast exception : 
            // DerivedClass derivedObjectOut = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<DerivedClass>(stream);
            // var objectOut = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<DerivedClass>(stream);

            // no exception thrown but internal type of objectOut is unexpectedly BaseClass : 
            var objectOut = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<DerivedClass>(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Produces the exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   protobuf-net.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'protobuf_net.lib.ProtoClasses.SimpleBaseClass' to type
>   'protobuf_net.lib.ProtoClasses.SimpleDerivedClass'.

Comment: @dbc thanks for catching those typos ( copy/paste from wrong source ) -- i've edited my post so the code matches the description

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a limitation or bug in protobuf-net here.  The way [`TypeModel.DeserializeCore()`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Meta/TypeModel.cs#L706) works is that it finds the **base** contract type, begins to deserialize as that type, and when it encounters a tag for a derived type, switches over to deserializing that type.  Finally, an object of the **observed** type is constructed and populated, causing the problem you see, since a tag for your desired derived type was never observed.

Fortunately, there's a simple workaround: use [`Serializer.Merge<T>()`](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/Serializer.cs#L65) to merge the stream into a pre-allocated instance of `DerivedType`:

```
var baseObject = new BaseClass { Name = "BaseObject" };

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, baseObject);
    Debug.WriteLine(stream.Length);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var derivedObjectOut = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Merge(stream, new DerivedClass());
}
```

It has a bit of code smell but fixes the problem.

Incidentally, in your original sample code you attempt to read the stream twice *without rewinding*.  That also throws an similar exception because *no* tags are encountered for the second call.

**Update**

If you are writing generic deserialization code, you could test for the presence of a `ProtoIncludeAttribute` somewhere in the inheritance hierarchy, and call `Merge()` if present, using the following helper method:

```
public static class ProtobufExtensions
{
    public static T DeserializeOrMerge<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsValueType
            && typeof(T) != typeof(string)
            // Test to make sure T has a public default constructor
            && typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
            && typeof(T).HasProtoIncludeAtributes())
        {
            return ProtoBuf.Serializer.Merge(stream, Activator.CreateInstance<T>());
        }
        else
        {
            return ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<T>(stream);
        }
    }

    public static bool HasProtoIncludeAtributes(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!type.IsDefined(typeof(ProtoContractAttribute)))
            return false;
        return type.BaseTypesAndSelf().SelectMany(t => t.GetCustomAttributes<ProtoIncludeAttribute>()).Any();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> BaseTypesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        while (type != null)
        {
            yield return type;
            type = type.BaseType;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
var baseObject = new BaseClass { NameInBaseClass = "BaseObject" };

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, baseObject);
    Debug.WriteLine(stream.Length);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var derivedObjectOut = ProtobufExtensions.DeserializeOrMerge<DerivedClass>(stream);
}
```

Comment: thanks @dbc the internals of protobuf-net are quite interesting. unfortunately , since i'm generating all the code related to serialization/deserialzation , it's going to be tricky to generate code that invokes the `Merge` form rather than the `Deserialize` form -- or are you saying it's ok to always use the `Merge` form ?